# ChangeMaker Issue with rounding pennies (keeps on removing one)

Tags: java

So I have to make a changemaker using methods and what not.
Lab says

Use the minimum number of coins. $1.39 also equals 0 quarters, 0 dimes, 0 nickels and 139 pennies, but you're not going to have a very successful career as a cashier if you make change in this way.
In this second program, keep your ChangeMaker class flexible by NOT having it include any input or output to/from the console. This way, it can be used in a console application, windows application, or web application!
Also, please note that I've included a toString() method which is a standard method that returns a string to describe the class.
Also test with $1.15 to make sure you get the right answer. This number gets stored as 1.14999999, so it needs some rounding to get it right. Be sure to handle this in your solution.

**Tester class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment1ChangeMaker {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ChangeMaker c1 = new ChangeMaker();
    System.out.print("Please set the amount of money that you wish to convert into change: $");
    c1.setMoney(sc.nextDouble());
    c1.calculateChange();
    System.out.println(c1.toString());      
    }

}
```

**Method Class**

```
public class ChangeMaker {
    private double money;
    private int numberOfQuarters;
    private int numberOfDimes;
    private int numberOfNickels;
    private int numberOfPennies;

public ChangeMaker(){
    money = 0.00;
    numberOfQuarters = 0;
    numberOfDimes = 0;
    numberOfNickels = 0;
    numberOfPennies = 0;
}

public double getMoney(){
    return money;
}
public void setMoney(double amount){
    this.money = (double) Math.round(amount * 100.0) / 100.0;
}
public void calculateChange(){
    numberOfQuarters = (int) Math.floor(money  / 0.25) ;
    numberOfDimes = (int) Math.floor((money - 0.25 * numberOfQuarters) / 0.10);
    numberOfNickels = (int) Math.floor((money - 0.25 * numberOfQuarters - 0.10 * numberOfDimes) / 0.05);
    numberOfPennies = (int) Math.floor((money - 0.25 * numberOfQuarters - 0.10 * numberOfDimes - 0.05 * numberOfNickels) / 0.01);
}
public String toString(){
   return "$" + money +" equals " + numberOfQuarters + " quarters, " + numberOfDimes + " dimes, " + numberOfNickels + " nickels, and " + numberOfPennies + " pennies.";
  }
}
```

It was going fine but whenever you input 1.4999999 you suddenly lose a penny. In fact, after doing some testing apparently it always loses a penny whenever there is one quarter, one dime, and more than 2 pennies.

For example:
$0.43 equals 1 quarters, 1 dimes, 1 nickels, and 2 pennies.
$1.13 equals 4 quarters, 1 dimes, 0 nickels, and 2 pennies.
$1.38 equals 5 quarters, 1 dimes, 0 nickels, and 2 pennies.
Working ones:
$1.09 equals 4 quarters, 0 dimes, 1 nickels, and 4 pennies.
$1.62 equals 6 quarters, 1 dimes, 0 nickels, and 2 pennies.
$1.12 equals 4 quarters, 1 dimes, 0 nickels, and 2 pennies.

Any help for this would be great. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `double`, it may be a better idea to store the money as an integer representing the number of pennies. This should allow you to eliminate all the floating-point arithmetic in `calculateChange()`, which could be what's causing the loss of information.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
private int numberOfPennies;

public void setMoney(double money) {
    numberOfPennies = (int) Math.round(money * 100);
}

public void calculateChange() {
    // subtract 25s, then 10s, then 5s, then 1s, until 0.
}
```

Comment: I tried to do as above, and it still shows up as:                                       Please set the amount of money that you wish to convert into change: $1.149999
$1.15 equals 4 quarters, 1 dimes, 0 nickels, and 4 pennies.

Comment: I've found the problem. Apparently there is a floating point precision error, there any way to fix it?

Comment: If you calculate the number of pennies with the function above, you will get f(1.14999999) = 115. Maybe you have a comparison error (< instead of <=)?

Comment: Oh sorry I should have said I fixed it already. I just confused about why money was being used as the variable for a method. yeah the one above works.